# Do you know eclipse plugin to change localised text into html entities?

Tags: html, eclipse, plugins

I have resource bundle with my country characters - how to change them into html entities.
I prefer plugin integrated with Eclipse to have all tools in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try:

http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/

Further down the page one of its features is:

*Convert 
Chars to Html entities
Editors -   Useful if working in bilingual team to convert é's, ô's, ä's etc between html and other sources ;)*